# How do you make Basecamp work for scrum?

Tags: scrum, pm-software, process

How do you use basecamp's fairly rigid tools for facilitating the scrum PM framework?

Comment: Is use of Basecamp mandated?  Why is an electronic tool required?

Comment: It's not mandated but allowing people to work remotely at times means a physical board gets updated less often and it's impossible review when not in the office.  We use basecamp for the rest of the company project management right now and keeping one tool to check makes things simpler for everyone.

Answer (score 8):

I used basecamp with scrum for over a year.  It was wonderful and I wish I could go back.

Excellent writeup here [how to do scrumxp with basecamp](https://web.archive.org/web/20110923153209/http://highnotes.posterous.com/how-to-do-scrumxp-with-basecamp)
The key ingredient is the burndowngraph.com tool.

With modifications to that, here's how we ran it...

I kept one todo list as the product backlog. (When things were very crazy at first, we used a spreadsheet, but use what works for you).  For those that required more description we would use the comments to add what we needed.  Normally this was acceptance criteria, mockups and "gotchas" that we didn't want to forget about.

During each sprint planning meeting, we grab the stories from the top and break each out into its own todo list.  Then for tasking we would create a todo item for each task and use the "6h" method of marking the estimate so burndowngraph.com would pick it up.

Sprint planning summary, retrospective, and items completed were all logged as messages.  For very detailed items, we would sometimes use a writeboard to log the "spec". An attached word doc would work just as well.

Comment: man how I love basecamp.... :)

Comment: All links are broken. The answer might have been good, but is useless now :(

Comment: Wayback Machine is your friend - https://web.archive.org/web/20120208211406/http://highnotes.posterous.com/how-to-do-scrumxp-with-basecamp